# Google Map not displaying at all in IE10

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer, drupal-7

The current [webpage](http://www.castolin.com/contact) isn't showing the gmap at all under IE10 but all the other browsers are able to display it properly. Can someone guide me through a possible solution?

I've tried the 
    META http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=9
    and
    META http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=edge

without success!
I'm currently using drupal 7 for the website and a gmap module.

Thanks for the replies

Comment: Check your console.log for warnings: `Control is no longer supported in the Google Maps Javascript API v2. Please visit https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/v2tov3 to migrate your application to v3. %7Bmain,adsense,geometry,zombie%7D.js:70
Map.addControl is no longer supported in the Google Maps Javascript API v2. Please visit https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/v2tov3 to migrate your application to v3.`

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment Anto! I'll be trying a google map Api key V3 and hope it will resolve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I have identify your error why it is giving this error it is because You have set this meta tag 
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">`

As per IE10 Browser Standard mode and Other Browser version IE8 Standard which is not support the Console's Following method

```
Console.log();
Console.info();
Console.warn();
```

But, If you can set the IE mode to 9 it will be work.

In IE10 Version there is 4 different methods are available in which `Console.dir()` is used instead of above 3.

In your Javascript file give this error:

```
"SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'warn' Bmain,adsense,geometry,zombie.js, line 70 character 35".
```

In that case you cannot change the javascript because it is load from the Google CDN.

So, possible you can add the following to your HTML will help you to change the Document Standard Mode to IE=9.
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">`

Reff: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj819729(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ashwin can you please tell me how to change the content="IE=9" in drupal 7 please? Thanks for your response

Comment: he following code example demonstrates how to force a webpage to be rendered in Internet Explorer 9 mode.
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />`